# Checking a one-dimensional numpy array in a multidimensional array without a loop

Tags: python, numpy

**Input**

```
array([[10, 11, 12, 13, 26, 28, 11],
       [ 4,  9, 19, 20, 21, 26, 12],
       [ 1,  7, 10, 23, 28, 32, 16],
       [ 4,  6,  7, 10, 13, 25,  3],
       [ 4,  6, 15, 17, 30, 31, 16]])

test = np.array([10, 11, 12, 13, 26, 28, 11])
```

**Trying**

```
def check(test,array):
    for i in array:
        if np.array_equal(i,test):
            print('in')
            break 
    print('not in')
```

Is there any simple method without using `for...in...if...else` structure?

Comment: I thought that, but then I checked it and it doesn't work for numpy arrays.

Comment: i, obviously, didn't take my pills this morning. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed ways. The most pythonic one is probably to use a generator comprehension.

```
def check(test,array):
    return any(numpy.array_equal(x, test) for x in array)
```

Note that this is not quite the same behaviour as it returns a Boolean rather than printing the result, but that behaviour should be easy enough to add outside.

---

As an aside, I don't like the variable name `test`. It sounds to me like the name of a predicate function rather than the name of an array you want to look for.

The name `check` is also rather too general to usefully say what it is checking.

Now I'm perhaps overly fond of slightly too descriptive names, but I'd probably be calling this `def is_row_in_array(row, array):`

Comment: What about `any(map(lambda x:np.array_equal(x,test), array))` ? Is it more pythonic?

Comment: That's controversial. As near as I can tell the trend is slightly to prefer comprehensions, and in particular to prefer comprehensions when you would otherwise have to define a lambda. Performance concerens also prefer comprehensions to map with a lambda. Of course some people, including myself, do find map more natural to think in. I actually wrote the map version in this answer before translating it to a generator comprehension!

Comment: For a bit of history about just how controversial, Guido van Rossum, the original creator of Python tried to drop map, filter and lambda from Python 3! https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like the looping and the `if ...` statements you could use solely NumPy methods:

```
def is_row_in_array(row , arr):
    return np.any(np.sum(np.abs(arr-row), axis=1) == 0)
```

Comment: `(arr == row).all(axis=1).any()` is shorter and a bit faster, but the general approach in this answer is right.

Comment: @Gareth Rees, nice improvement.